# Spy on a method passed into a mocked node module

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am building a client that will wrap the `SignalR` library:

```
export class RealTimeCommunicator {

  /** SignalR hub connection */
  private hubConnection: HubConnection | null = null;

  private buildConnection(url: string): HubConnection {
    return new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(url)
    .build();
  }

  public subscribe(onStart: () => void, success: (data: IVehicleInfo) => void, fail?: (err: Error) => void): () => void {
    this.hubConnection = this.buildConnection("/someurl");
    this.hubConnection.on("send", data => {
      success(data);
    });

    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(onStart)
      .catch(err => fail && fail(err));

    return this.unsubscribe;
  }

  public subscribeToVehicleDetails(vehicleId: number, success: (data: IVehicleInfo) => void, fail?: (err: Error) => void): () => void {
    return this.subscribe(() => this.hubConnection!.invoke("EnrolInVehicleGroupAsync", vehicleId), success, fail);
  }
```

I want to test it, but mock out `SignalR`, so I added `__mocks__/@aspnet/signalr.ts` to the solution:

```
let SignalR = jest.genMockFromModule("@aspnet/signalr");

class HubConnection {

  public on(methodName: string, callback: () => string): Promise<void> {
    this.successCallback = callback;
    return Promise.resolve()
  }

  public start(): Promise<void> { return Promise.resolve() }

  public successCallback: () => string = () => "failure";
}

let hubConnection = new HubConnection();

let HubConnectionBuilder = () => ({
  withUrl: (url) => ({
    build: () => hubConnection
  })
});

SignalR = {
  HubConnectionBuilder: HubConnectionBuilder,
  HubConnection: hubConnection
};

module.exports = SignalR;
```

I am attempting to spy on the `on` method to ensure it was called, and as a stretch goal confirm that my success handler was registered correctly.

```
import { RealTimeCommunicator } from "./RealTimeCommunicator";
jest.mock('SignalR');

describe("RTC", () => {
  test("foo", () => {
    const ConnectionBuilder = require("SignalR").HubConnectionBuilder;

    const connection = new ConnectionBuilder().withUrl("").build();

    const spy = jest.spyOn(connection, 'on');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  //Expectation fails
    const successText = "success!";
    const successCallBack: () => string = () => successText;
    const rtc = new RealTimeCommunicator();

    rtc.subscribeToVehicleDetails(1, successCallBack, _ => _);
    expect(connection.successCallback()).toBe(successText); // connection.successCallback is undefined
  })
});
```

If I place breakpoints in my `SignalR` mock, I can see that `on` is being invoked, but the spy doesn't see it. Also the `successCallback` that I bolted onto my mock is coming back as `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, you just need two changes.

---

Return the result of `success(data)`:

```ts
public subscribe(onStart: () => void, success: (data: IVehicleInfo) => void, fail?: (err: Error) => void): () => void {
  this.hubConnection = this.buildConnection("/someurl");
  this.hubConnection.on("send", data => {
    return success(data);   // return the result
  });

  this.hubConnection.start()
    .then(onStart)
    .catch(err => fail && fail(err));

  return this.unsubscribe;
}
```

---

Wait to assert that `spy` has been called until *after* you call `rtc.subscribeToVehicleDetails`:

```ts
const spy = jest.spyOn(connection, 'on');
const successText = "success!";
const successCallBack: () => string = () => successText;
const rtc = new RealTimeCommunicator();

rtc.subscribeToVehicleDetails(1, successCallBack, _ => _);
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();   // SUCCESS
expect(connection.successCallback()).toBe(successText);   // SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide any working sample (e.g. in form of a repo) to reproduce your problem? As far as I can see, there are some flaws in the provided code snippets.

First of all, why is `jest.mock('SignalR');` actually working? *SignalR* is not an module which should throw an error. You should mock the module you're actually importing: `jest.mock('@aspnet/signalr');`. Except of that, your first part of the test consists of testing an third party library - why are you doing this at all, except of checking if your mock is working?

Second, you're checking if the `on` method was called **instantly** after creating the spy. Though, the spy only registers calls made after it was created. What you may want is to make the *on* method a spy by default:

```
// in __mocks__/@aspnet/signalr.ts

class HubConnection {

  public on = jest.fn().mockImplementation((methodName: string, callback: () => string) => {
    this.successCallback = callback;
    return Promise.resolve()
  });


  // ...

}
```

Third, the *connection* you are creating in the test is a different one from the one you create later on using *subscribeToVehicleDetails*, therefore the successCallback would still return "failure" if it'd be working.